# AngularJS - Close modal function not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have made a simple pop up window by using `ui.bootstrap` but I can't seem to make the OK and CLOSE button to work. What am I missing in this sample codes?

Here is the sample code from [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UsoCyFdc91Mqa48o6kTB?p=preview)

Thank you

**added exact code image

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`close` and `dismiss` are methods of `$modalInstance` object returned by `$modal.open`:

```
$scope.open = function() {
    $scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
        scope: $scope,
        templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
        size: '',
    })
};

$scope.ok = function() {
    $scope.$modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

One more problem with your code is that you need to specify `scope: $scope` in modal config. This is necessary if you want the scope inside modal template to be a child scope of the one, where you are defining `ok/cancel` methods.

#### Fixed demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5s4yPm1TZB8S9nfO5CA?p=preview

Comment: can i further check with you i follow your guide to impliment it, but it says "Cannot read property 'close' of undefined"... what about it? thanks

Comment: it means that you are doing something wrong. Are you sure you call `close` method of the object returned by `$modal.open()`?

Comment: i have added the exact code i have now in the above image... am i still missing something?

Comment: Yes, also add `scope: $scope`: `$scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({ scope: $scope, templateUrl: "modalContent.html", size: ''})`.

Comment: New to Angular, and all the modal examples show other controllers and are complicated. The `$scope` value helped me out a lot!!! The close was not able to find where the heck to go without it :) Thanks!

Comment: It seems, they (Bootstrap or Angular) have changed something in latest versions: I get `$scope.$modalInstance.close is not a function`

Comment: @JustAMartin No, they didn't change API, it's still `close`. You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @dfsq - please take a look at this Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/8Mm5cA9v6ksJ1fYoaVSN?p=preview - close() does not work if attached to the same $scope as current controller.

Comment: Oh, never mind, it was an assignment issue - the then() call returned promise and not the modal object.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code with a working version

http://plnkr.co/edit/iM5o0le3OioqxHBNF3d1?p=preview

There are a few things wrong with your code.

$modal is a factory, you can't call $modal.close()

You would need to do something like:

```
 this.modal = $modal(....)

 this.modal.close();
```

Still, even if you did this in your controller, your modal view does not have access to the scope.

The solution in the forked plunk I offer is to use

```
  ng-click="$parent.$close()"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways as explained before and it depends in which context you need to use it.

For example if the modal is just a notification, there's no need to use functions for the buttons OK or CANCEL, just using $dismiss() or $close() in the ng-click of the buttons located in the modalContent.html file will be enough.

Here is also an updated plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/OfCGJX?p=preview

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```